# Changing app id on Chromecast sender

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have a Chromecast sender application that can be used to launch multiple `app id`s for testing purposes.

In the Chromecast docs, it says that the `setOptions` function should only be called once. And indeed when calling it a second time, the `receiverApplicationId` property can't be modified.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/cast.framework.CastContext#setOptions

This works:

`cast.framework.CastContext.qa.s.receiverApplicationId = receiverApplicationId;`

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Each sender app should be launched with a single app id only.

Comment: Correct, but we have an html sender app that multiple people use for development purposes. It'd be nice to be able to launch multiple app ids from this page without doing a full reload.